# (file-error "Cannot open load file" ... error message in emacs

Tags: emacs

Invoking emacs, I got these error message.

```
Error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "starter-kit-defuns")
Error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "tex-site")
```

Looking into my .emacs.d directory, I see no "starter-kit-defuns" nor "tex-site" in it. I also don't remember explicitly install them.

Why do I have these errors? How to remove/resolve them?

[image]

This is the content of my init.el file. -> https://gist.github.com/prosseek/ec47ea3569b6f02721cf

Comment: Does that happens with "emacs -q"?  If yes, what about "emacs -Q"?

Comment: @juanleon: I see no messages with -q.

Comment: Try starting emacs with `--debug-init`. That should give you a backtrace that might point to where this comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing emacs, I used `brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --cocoa --srgb` command as is described in [this site](http://struct.tumblr.com/post/46754394733/emacs-24-use-homebrew-instead-of-emacsformacosx). However, it seems that there are some bugs with the newest version - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-09/msg00135.html.

When I reinstalled emacs with `brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb`, the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating emacs through MacPorts. The "tex-site" error can be resolved by removing and re-installing your auctex using `M-x package-list-packages`.